# How to rearrange buttons on Vaadin ConfirmDialog?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin ConfirmDialog.
By default, the order of buttons displayed is Cancel followed by OK at the bottom right end. How can this be changed to display OK first followed by Cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ConfirmDialog use DefaultConfirmDialogFactory to create interface.

If you want to customize buttons positioning and other you must create Factory from the scratch or override DefaultConfirmDialogFactory.

On ConfirmDialog you have setFactory() method.

On the link: [DefaultConfirmDialogFactory](https://github.com/samie/Vaadin-ConfirmDialog/blob/master/src/org/vaadin/dialogs/DefaultConfirmDialogFactory.java) you can see default code.